# Como puedo actualizar una ruta de imagen con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal tengo este código con el cual puedo subir las imágenes a una carpeta y guardar su ruta en mi base de datos

```
     $extensiones = array('.jpg','.JPG','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.svg');
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $alt = $_POST['alt'];
    $nombreImagen= $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $nombreTempImagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $ruta="img/".$nombreImagen;
    $ext = substr($nombreImagen,strpos($nombreImagen,'.'));
    if(in_array($ext,$extensiones)){
        $sql="INSERT INTO banner_index (Nombre_img,ruta_img,alt) VALUES ('$nombre','$ruta','$alt')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
            move_uploaded_file($nombreTempImagen,"../img/$nombreImagen");
            header("Location:admin");
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
        
    }else{
        echo "Archivo no valido";
    }
}
```

Pero ahora quisiera cambiar la consulta para que en lugar de insertar simplemente me actualice el registro y lo unico que cambie fue la consulta y quedo de esta manera:

```
    $extensiones = array('.jpg','.JPG','.jpeg','.png','.gif','.svg');
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $alt = $_POST['alt'];
    $nombreImagen= $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $nombreTempImagen = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $ruta="img/".$nombreImagen;
    $ext = substr($nombreImagen,strpos($nombreImagen,'.'));
    if(in_array($ext,$extensiones)){
        $sql="UPDATE banner_index SET Nombre_img = $nombre, ruta_img=$ruta,alt=$alt WHERE id_img = '42'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result){
            move_uploaded_file($nombreTempImagen,"../img/$nombreImagen");
            header("Location:admin");
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
        
    }else{
        echo "Archivo no valido";
    }
}
```

El problema es que no me esta funcionando, me manda al error del else, entonces no se que es lo que debería modificar

Comment: Te faltan la comillas simples, como en el INSERT.

Comment: que wey, tienes razon jaja gracias